# Making a plot of a sumfunction

Tags: plot

I want to make plots for different values of k of this function:

```
$\mathbb{P}[A=n] = \frac{1}{k} \cdot  \sum_{l=0}^{n} \frac{l^{n-1} (k-1)^{n-l}}{e^{kl} \cdot l!(n-l)!}$
```

Can anyone help me?

Best,
Claudia

Comment: Do you want to show `P(n)` with `k=...`  or `P(k)` with `n=...`?